# unable to sign an apk file

Tags: java, android, apk

I generated an apk file for my project, but when I wanted to put it in “Play Store”, I did not manage to do it, because a problem of signature!

These are the instructions I made:

1)

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias
```

2)

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.jks app-unsigned.apk my-alias
```

3)

```
/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.2/zipalign -v 4 app-unsigned.apk app-signed.apk
```

4)

```
/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.2/apksigner verify app-signed.apk
```

The first 3 commands give a message of success operation, but the last one gives this error:

```
DOES NOT VERIFY ERROR: JAR signer CERT.RSA: JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?
```

On the other hand, i used Android Studio to generate the app file signed, but there was another error message:

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can’t find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale fr_FR java.util.MissingResourceException: …
```

Can you tell me why this problem accur?

Comment: Follow the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signing-manually

Comment: Thank you, but when i excuted this command "./gradlew assembleRelease" , an error message is displayed:
An exception occurred while trying to find the Android build tools.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script '/Users/mac/Desktop/Projets/cielapp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 121
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Unable to determine Android SDK directory.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Did you set the ANDROID_HOME variable?

Comment: `jarsigner` is the outdated (and less secure) tool for creating signatures - you should use `apksigner` instead.

Comment: Yes Patrick, i added it in .bash_profile

Comment: Robert ! I used apksigner just for verification (you can see the topic above) but i don't know how to use it for signature instead of jarsigner

Answer (score 0):

Now, the problem is resolved!

I think that i have error in original apk file in building, because when i built an other one by other method, the operation pass successfully !

This is the link of instructions where i found solution :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Thank you.